# Can I pass a JavaScript variable to PHP to use as the URL for a cURL function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl

I have a working cURL function that allows me to bypass the Cross Domain issue, this is the code below

```
<?php

$url = "http://explorerapi.barratthomes.co.uk/v2.0/development/getbyitemkey?ItemKey=H618701&Auth.Utc=2015-07-31T08:30:26.761Z&Auth.RequestId=a22a17d8-8d62-4954-8a9c-79e5c244c308&Auth.DeviceId=23a5bb10-c646-47c4-8fda-1b6f1d528de3&Auth.Hash=052DAA8E425F143D4B5C55A1EAC87C5D&BrandCode=BAR&ApplicationId=ApplicationId&ApplicationVersion=1.2.3.4&LanguageCode=en-gb&IsPublished=true&MarketingSuiteDevelopmentId=MarketingSuiteDevelopmentId&UserLocation=UserLocation&Os=Android&ScreenResolution=1024x768&Hierarchical=True";

        $cu = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($cu, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);

        $result = curl_exec($cu);

        if(curl_errno($cu))
        {
            echo "<h2>Unable to connect to site</h2>";
        }

        curl_close($cu);
echo $result;

?>
```

This works fine when I set the url as seen here. However The url is dynamic and is different each time,  therefore I have a JavaScript file which creates the URL and puts it into a variable.

I am having trouble getting the JavaScript variable into PHP so I can use the URL. I have been trying with `$_GET` and `$_POST` but having no luck.

Here is my Java for reference the address variable is coming from my JavaScript file that creates the URL.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/auth.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <script type='text/javascript'>

            var url = address;

        $(document).ready(function() {

            window.location.href = "test.php?url_=" + url;

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:4001/Barratt/test.php",
                //dataType: 'json',
                //method: 'GET',
                //contentType: 'application/json'
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                  //var response = $.parseJSON(data.contents);
                $('#value').html(data);
                  })
            .fail(function() {
                alert('failed to fetch data')
            });
        });   

        </script>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 2px solid red;" id="value">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think probably because of this:

in ur JS code, u need to pass a parameter to the server like:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:4001/Barratt/test.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{url:'http://your.url.here'},
        //better to use post in case ur url got special characters
        method: 'POST', 
    });
```

Then in ur php code, u will be able to get the url using $_POST[]:

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
```

Then i think that will do.

Comment: That's done the trick, thanks very much. Made my Friday much better :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I see it right, but I don't see the super globals $_GET or $_POST being used in your php script.

Are you aware that if you POST a value to a php file it will end up in the super global array $_POST. (and the same for $_GET)

So if you call my.php?value=test it will end up in:

```
$get_value = strip_tags($_GET['value']); // The strip tags is just some safty thing
if (isset($get_Value))
     // do things with your get_value here
```

Comment: I've tried that and for some reason the API doesn't like the URL,  I get a `NoCallContext` error from the server

Comment: @Pedroson and the url is filled? also, is the url url_encoded? else considder using `method : "POST", data : {"url" : url}`    Chen's answer here descibes that post method better.